# Try to change style in current month in chartJS

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

This is my first question here as a junior software developer, so don't expect so much experience hahaha.

I'm trying to do a graphic with chartJS (Using Angular), and i want to highligh the current month with bold or black color, but i don't know how to.

I want something like this aprox:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mTOC.png)

Do you know if it's possible?

Thank you all! ^-^

Comment: Please ass your code because answers will vary depending on how you approached your chart, so without it its hard to help and answers will likely not be of much help

Answer (score -1):

I think it does not matter if you work with angular as it is a chart.js thing.
Check how you can configure the ticks (axis values are called ticks) [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html).

Find this code modification to configure each of the ticks:

```
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart with Tick Configuration'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          // For a category axis, the val is the index so the lookup via getLabelForValue is needed
          callback: function(val, index) {
            // Hide the label of every 2nd dataset
            return index % 2 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
          },
          color: 'red',
          font: {
            weight: (w) => { //4th x axis index will be bold
              return w.index === 4 ? '900' : 'normal'; 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
};
```

You can paste that right there in the documentation page and check how it works.
To choose the degree of boldness you like, give lookd to the [documentaion](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/fonts.html). It is the `weight` property the one you need to set.

Edit:

Find the 4th x tick bolded:

[image]

Comment: This answer does not solve what OP is asking, you copyed an example from the chart.js website and pasted it here while it indeed changes things it does not highlight the current month

Comment: thanks for your comment. I extended the code if the documentation sample with the OP needs. If you copy/paste my snippet in the code of the documentation itself you can check that the 4th month is bold

Comment: changed line from `'bold'` to `'900'` for the bold to be more clear. Here: `return w.index === 4 ? '900' : 'normal';`

Comment: Yeah but you expect the 4th value to be the current month which it might not be

Comment: Depending on if a category or time scale is used and autoskip it might not even show up

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean, my chartjs knowledge is not very deep. Sure there are many things and scenarios where it may not work. Just trying to provide some fast and easy to see working snippet that answers the question to help the OP

Comment: the logic that retrieves the current month and that relates it with the chart index is left to the OP. I dont think that is the important part of the question IMHO. Moreover when the OP is not providing neither his chart, attempt or data

Comment: Thank You so much rusty! I'm going to try it right now, it seems clear and easy to put in my code :) Thanks again, i'll come back to tell how it's going ^-^